# find new and remove array element form two array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array

```
$a1     = array('1'=>'1', '2'=>'2', '3'=>'3', '4'=>'4', '5'=>'5', '6'=>'6');
$a2     = array('1'=>'1', '2'=>'2', '3'=>'3', '6'=>'6', '7'=>'7', '8'=>'8');
```

i want to get two array as output first array which return those element which has been removed form first array.
second array which return new element

Comment: see http://www.whathaveyoutried.com for an insight about how you should ask technical questions if you're looking for help.

Answer (score 1):

To get an array which has all the elements that are no longer in the second array, you can use [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>

Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

To get an array with all the elements that are in both arrays (not removed) you can use [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>

Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1   = array('1'=>'1', '2'=>'2', '3'=>'3', '4'=>'4', '5'=>'5', '6'=>'6');
$a2   = array('1'=>'1', '2'=>'2', '3'=>'3', '6'=>'6', '7'=>'7', '8'=>'8');
$out1 = array_diff($a1,$a2);
$out2 = array_diff($a2,$a1);
```